# Animate the color of rectangle

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to change the color of rectangle after a certain period of time.

I tried root.after() method but it is not working.

```
    import time
    from tkinter import *

    def task():
      canvas= Canvas()
      canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100,fill='red')
      canvas.pack()
      time.sleep(2)
      canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100,fill='blue')
      canvas.pack()
      time.sleep(2)
      print("Testing...")


    root = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(root)
    while(1):
      task()
      root.mainloop()
```

Given code running continuously and root windows get hang for certain time. Rectangle color should change after 2 seconds of delay.

Comment: `task()` will be executed only once because `root.mainloop()` will block the while loop.  You should use `after()`.  What have you tried using `after()`?

Comment: I used after() in function as well as in main() function. root.mainloop()  was wrong in my code. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `time.sleep()` hangs the window as well as `while` loop. To use `time.sleep`
in tkinter we use `after(ms)` (ms-milliseconds) in the functions so the GUI won't hang.

While does the same, so we use `after(ms, callback, args)` function.

Here is an example of what you are trying to achieve. The rectangle will change his color every 1000ms (1 sec) from red to blue - blue to red so on. Also in your code you were creating a new canvas and rectangle every 4 secs. What I did is, I defined one canvas and one rectangle outside the `task()` function and gave the rectangle a tag `(tag='rect')` for the reference through which edit that one rectangle's color without creating unnecessary items. I hope this helped you.

**Example:**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100,fill='red', tag='rect')

def task():
    l = root.after(1000, task)

    if int(l.split('#')[1]) % 2 == 0:
        canvas.itemconfig('rect', fill='blue')
    else: 
        canvas.itemconfig('rect', fill='red')

task()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks **Saad**  for your answer. It really helped me. Can you do it for more than 2 colors?

Comment: Yes, you can do as many colors as you want but the approach will be different. If you need random colors you can make a list of all colors you want and then choice one, in that case you don't even need `if-else`. But if you want the colors in sequence then the code might take few `if-elif` statements.